# ggparcoord y axis scale to (1, 10, 100, 1000)

Tags: r, scale, axis

Hi I have a problem changing the scale using ggparcoord
please tell me how to change y axis value to (1, 10, 100, 1000)

```r
p<- ggparcoord(dt1, columns = c(108,111), groupColumn = 155, order = "anyClass", scale = "globalminmax", showPoints = TRUE, 
           alphaLines = 0.3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, we don't have your data, so let's make a dummy example that is similar to yours:

```r
library(GGally)

set.seed(8)
dt1 <- data.frame(BNP = rexp(500, 0.001),
                  BNP_Max3 = rexp(500, 0.001),
                  minusDeltaBNP = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 250))

p <- ggparcoord(dt1, columns = 1:2, groupColumn = 3,
                scale = "globalminmax", showPoints = TRUE, alphaLines = 0.3) +
     theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

To change the y axis to a log scale, we can simply do:

```r
p + scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>